# Publishing status Rejected

Tags: android, google-play-console

[image: this Screen Short of rejected apk]

**I am trying to upload apk on play console from 1 week with call_phone and SMS permission but it rejected from play console. i have also filled the notice form before uploading apk on play console and also described the all required permission functions.**

Comment: Refer this Documentation
**https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/**




If your app need to read sms for SMS-based user verification / OTP verification please use **SMS Retriever API** which does not needed any sms permission and your app can still read SMS for OTP verification.

Comment: @Rakesh R  but want to send sms .

Comment: @Rakesh R Is there any api for send sms automatically

Comment: Automatically ?? In the sense, without user knowledge ?

Comment: No, While Registration we will take mobile number and save it in server after that if the user need to to call in emergency situation user need to click once in a app and the registered number will dialled automatically.

Comment: Your description says, Calling function. But why you need SMS permission ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207401/discussion-between-vickey-rajak-and-rakesh-r).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about policies related to the play store and not about coding, have a look at [why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Comment: any one can please help me